# ASP.NET MVC 2 form submit route issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, controller, master-pages

i'm having this issue, in ASP.NET MVC 2 where I'm adding a drop down list on the master page and filling it with data from an abstract master controller. When an option is selected an submit button clicked, it reroutes you to a new page. so lets say

the page lives on http://domain.com/landingPage

1. i'm on: http://domain.com/landingPage
2. i select option and submit
3. takes me to http://domain.com/landingPage/Projects/FramedPage
4. i select again and now the post tries to go to: http://domain.com/landingPage/Projects/landingPage/Projects/FramedPage because of the action="" i have set on the form tag.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

**MasterPage**:

```
<form method="get" action="landingPage/Projects/FramedPage">
 <%= Html.DropDownList("navigationList")%>
 <input id="navSubmitBtn" class="btnBlue" type="submit" value="Take Me There" />
</form>
```

**Projects Controller**

public ActionResult FramedPage(string navigationList)
  {
   ViewData["navLink"] = navigationList;

return View();
  }

The problem i am having is that if I am ON that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative location.

> ```
> <form method="get" action="<%=Url.Action("FramedPage", "ControllerName") %>">
> ```